# COLDFUSION CFGRID Datapass with a post

Tags: ajax, post, coldfusion, cfgrid

I have a bit of a unique challenge today. I have a client that wants to be able to search for multiple items based on inserts into a cfgrid. Suppose we have the following web form:

- A Country selection dropdown
- A State Selection dependent AJAX dropdown
- A city Selection dependent AJAX dropdown
- An ADD Button
  ----------------------------------------------------
- A CFGRID that will populate a row with selections when the user clicks the add button
  ----------------------------------------------------
- And finally, a CLEAR button, and a GO button on the bottom.

The resulting page will then query the database and get some statistics about the cities selected. So, suppose an individual picks USA > Arizona > Scottsdale and USA > Arizona > Flagstaff. The grid below the options will 'save' each selection and reset to their default options, waiting for a user to pick additional options or click on 'GO'.

The resulting page will then generate columns that list some statistics about the communities and highlight the 'best of' between each selected community.

Each time a user selects the ADD button (assuming three criteria are selected) I want the information to be added into a CFGRID that displays the options selected. Then, After the user selects at least one country/city/state option, have all of the data in the CFGRID get passed to another page that does a query from the data selected. In theory, the user could pick as many communities as they want, assuming they are willing to let the database sludge through enough data to get what they want and wait through a 'loading' screen to get it.

I'm having these challenges, in no particular order:
- I have an HTML grid that I must use per client spec (No Java or Flash, must be HTML)
- I have no idea how to get the selected options into the CFGRID. I assume there is some JavaScript I can write that uses some sort of AddRow function to add data into the grid with the add button but cannot seem to find how to it on the interwebs
- After we conquer the above challenge, how do I pass the data from the grid into the results page? I thought about passing one big string or a structure, but I'm not sure how to do that through the URL or posting, nor how to get the data out of the grid. I wonder if I am better off coding some sort of string that gets passed from the options page to the results page with a get method instead of dealing with the stuff in the CFGRID and have the CFGRID serve only as a 'dummy' display container.
- Finally, after the pass is complete, I would need to loop through through the structure and perform a CFQUERY or CFSTOREDPROC on each row of data, then get the statistics I need to display on the results page. I assume this would depend on how I am getting the data from the options selection page to the results page.

THANK YOU ALL!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that the best way to handle this was by using a SerializeJSON call and a Deserialize JSON call back and forth. By using JavaScript notation we are able to pass a complex JavaScript object (array) between one page and another. This has the value add of not having to worry about sessions timing out and making URLs clickable from one solution to the next.

Answer (score 1):

CFGRID is great to start, but it can be b*tch to customize and extend... Have you tried editable CFGRID with bind? See how far off it is from what you want first.  If it turns out to be very far, then you might want to go for a jqGrid and code up some jQuery.

To start, read **Using HTML grids** and make the cfgrid editable.
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7a01.html#WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-72e0

Once you got that working, look at these provided JS functions that you can use with CFGRID

- http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WS0ef8c004658c1089-6262c847120f1a3b244-8000.html
- http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSd160b5fdf5100e8f-4439fdac128193edfd6-7f5f.html

If you still demand a bit more, you might need to dig into the underlying ExtJS component.  At that point I would rather use jqGrid

Comment: I'll add my +1 to jquery instead of cfgrid. Using it to any degree beyond the tutorials and samples provided is a hair pulling experience :)

Comment: Alright. Let's suppose that I take the JQuery route on this instead of the CFGRID route. How would you perform the pass?